# Change the use of the "Game" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was scrolling through the posts tagged with "Game" and noticed that it involved quite a few code golf competitions. Just for the sake of clarity and ease while searching, I believe that the definitions of some tags should be clarified to be as follows:

1. Challenge: A play thing with an objective.
2. Competition: A challenge taken by multiple players where the players can not interfere with each other, but otherwise are trying to be better than the other players.
3. Game: A challenge, except that the players can interfere with each other.

I got the definitions from [this Vsauce video starting at around 2:45](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5jDspIC4hY)

Under these new definitions, a typical code golf should be tagged with "competition", things like "king-of-the-hill" are classified as a "game".

Answer (score 9):

[game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) does clarify to which challenges it applies. From [its tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/game/info):

> This challenge is generally based upon, related to, or simulates a game or some portion of one.

> Use the more specific tags over this one: [tic-tac-toe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe), [sudoku](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku), [boggle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boggle), [manufactoria](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manufactoria), [game-of-life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-life). For specific types of games, use [board-game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-game), [maze](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maze), [cellular-automata](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-automata)

That means both code golf and KotH challenges can bear the game tag, assuming they're based on games.

Your definition of game as *a challenge, except that the players can interfere with each other* is the actual definition of [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill). Its wiki excerpt says:

> King-of-the-hill indicates a game where the submissions interact with and compete against each other in some form of game. Competitions which pit programs against each other without interaction should rather use [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge).

So redefining the game tag would just make it a synonym of the KoTH tag.

Finally, a competition tag would apply to pretty much all challenges except KoTH, so it feels a bit redundant.